# Error 502 when upgrade magento 2.2.3 to 2.2.9

Tags: magento2, nginx, magento-upgrade, magento2.2.9

We're facing a weird issue, we were working with `Magento 2.2.3` by a year aprox. and decided to upgrade our `Magento` open source version to `2.2.9`:

- We made a clean installation of `Magento 2.2.9`  in our CI `env`.
- Imported catalog through `cvs` file generated by our `Magento 2.2.3`.
- Our server has 2G of memory and `PHP 7.1` has memory limit 1G

all fine with the installation for clean CI enviroment, but when browse  some products we get a 502 bad gateway `nginx error`, but only in some products, even if those products are in the same category with others similar products.

that didn't happen with 2.2.3, and really don't know what to do.

Comment: I faced similar issue, when i hit home page i got this error, i try to debug and found a block, i comment out that block and got no error, If you get this error on PDP, please see if your Product Detail Page (PDP) `xml` is overridden in your theme.

Comment: hi @PartabSaifuddinZakir im gonna check, but why this happens with certain products and not all of them ?

Comment: I don't know just try to debug the overridden PDP file on your custom theme.... maybe it's `catalog_product_view.xml`.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help, I will check and then answer back